# Dead woodsmen, a novel search

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel I can only remember one detail of, two or more characters are passing through the woods and come upon a charcoal makers camp that has been attacked by someone or something, the characters realise there's a problem when they encounter the smoke from the charcoal ovens burning out of control, I can't even remember if they find the woodsmen dead or just gone. I have the feeling the genre was either Fantasy, Steampunk or Alternative History but otherwise I'm stumped. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Related meta; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11667/20774

Comment: Can you clarify what about this makes you think it would be suitable for SFF:SE? In particular, you could go through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is almost certainly [Monstrous Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monstrous_Regiment_(novel)), by Terry Pratchett.  Supporting evidence is as follows:

- two or more characters are passing through the woods

  > After a few hours of this, when true dawn was breaking, they smelled smoke.  There was a faint pall of it among the trees.
- and come upon a charcoal makers camp

> "Charcoal oven," whispered Polly.  "Just clay plastered on a stack of hazel."

- that has been attacked by someone or something, the characters realise there's a problem when they encounter the smoke from the charcoal ovens burning out of control

> "The wind probably caught it last night and the fire's broken out.  Won't make good charcoal now, it's burning too fast."

then

> "The charcoal burner is dead, or nearly dead," said Polly.

and

> "They watch the burns like hawks," said Polly, staring at the hut.  "He wouldn't let it go out of control like that if he was alive."

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I was getting badly off track thinking it was a David Gemmell or a China Miéville, _Monsterous Regiment_ here I come.